# Creating multiple row per row based on date caclulation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have never done anything like it and not able to find any guidance when I google. How can I create multiple row based on one row data

For example here's my data:

```
Employee | EmploymentDate
1          1/1/2017
```

Every three months I need to calculate level.

```
Employee | EmploymentDate |  Level | LevelDateRange
1          1/1/2017          1       1/1/2017 - 3/31/2017
1          1/1/2017          2       4/1/2017 - 6/30/2017
1          1/1/2017          3       7/1/2017 - 9/30/2017
```

LevelDateRange Calculation:

```
Start Date: If 1st level then EmploymentDate 
            else previous LevelDateRange end date + 1
End Date: If 1st level then EmployemeentDate + 3 months minus a day 
          else Start date + 3 months
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is a new level record created every three months? Where is it stored as it is not in your table...

Comment: yes new record will be create every three months. Not stored anywhere, just creating a select statement with logic to accomplish what i described above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you might consider `cross apply`:

```
select d.employee, v.*
from mydata d cross apply
     (values (1, employmentdate, dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 3, d.employmentdate))),
             (2, dateadd(month, 3, employmentdate), dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 6, d.employmentdate))),
             (3, dateadd(month, 6, employmentdate), dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 9, d.employmentdate)))
     ) v(lev, startdate, enddate);
```

I would advise you to keep the start date and end date in separate columns.  Combine them into a string at the application level or when you query the database.

Answer (score 2):

A tally table and a CTE:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
SELECT @StartDate = EmploymentDate FROM emp
DECLARE @MonthsSinceStart INT = DATEDIFF(mm,@startDate,GETDATE())
DECLARE @NumLevels INT = @MonthsSinceStart / 3

--100 row tally table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tally') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Tally
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Level
INTO #Tally
FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n);

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  Employee,
            EmploymentDate,
            Level,
            EmploymentDate AS StartDate,
            DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(mm,3,EmploymentDate)) AS EndDate
    FROM    emp
            CROSS JOIN #Tally   
    WHERE   #Tally.Level =1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  Employee,
            EmploymentDate,
            Level + 1,
            DATEADD(dd,1,EndDate) AS StartDate,
            DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(mm,3,DATEADD(dd,1,EndDate))) AS EndDate
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   cte.Level < @NumLevels
)
SELECT  Employee,
        EmploymentDate,
        Level,
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),StartDate) + ' - ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),EndDate)
FROM cte;
```

Suggest you give it a test with more than one row in your table

Comment: Thank you! it worked great. Sorry I mean to reply earlier

Comment: Is there a way CTE can be avoided? CTEs are slow if you have a lot of data

Comment: There is another answer to this question by Gordon Linoff which doesn't use a CTE. Whilst I haven't tested that, in honesty it looks a better solution!

Comment: Ok I will look, by the way why are you diving @MonthsSinceStart  by 3 for @NumLevels? is it because I only used three months in my example? it will actually continue until it hits today's date. So max employment date would be <=today's date

Comment: It's because as per the comments in the original post, a new level record is created every three months, therefore the number of months since the start divided by 3 gives us the number of levels.